# .NET: dependentAssembly, bindingRedirect has wrong version

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I am trying to understand that when I added moq via nuget it created an app.config with the following information.

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Moq" publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.1309.801" newVersion="4.1.1309.801" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

The problem is that now I am getting an error like so

> Could not load file or assembly 'Moq, Version=4.1.1309.801,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The reason for this is basically my moq reference actually has this version

```
        4.1.1309.919
```

So I am confused, is there anyway to fix this ? Of course a quick and dirty way would be to manually edit the app.config file and place the correct version i.e. .919 but I have a lot of them.

Also i don't know why my app.config wasn't updated by nuget when my moq reference obviously was.

I don't suppose something like wildcards are supported in the attribute newVersion ???

I know if i remove the file it causes me other issues as I have a dependency on moq 3.0 so having this file there means it still supports the dependent reference and redirects it to 4.1.

This is what I understand, but I am not 100% sure, anybody help with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your assumption about the cause of the problem may be wrong.  The binding redirect should not effect your projects that reference 4.1.1309.919.  Most likely this is coming from a project that is referencing 3.0.  It seems that you actually have 4.1.1309.919 installed, you're referencing something between 0.0.0.0-4.1.1309.801, and because of the incorrect binding redirect, it is failing.

Can you identify which test project is failing with the exceptions and post the references section of the proj file?

Comment: Yes strange, this may have been the case, So when creating a new project is there anyway I can ensure i am using the same version in the new project as the old when it comes to nuget packages. I think this is what caused me an issue...Created a new project then added my nuget pacakges - but i think there was a newer version!

Comment: I'm uncertain about that.  I haven't used NuGet enough to be certain.  I thought that if you choose to "Manage NuGet Packages for Solution" rather than just add new, it would reuse the existing rather than download new.  At this point, you're probably stuck scanning your config and proj files to see which ones are referencing which versions and which are applying redirects.  It may be best to kill all the old references, the redirects, and recompile all your tests against the new version.